# How can Ysolda be able to take care of the Bannered Mare?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In some Skyrim videos I saw Ysolda taking care of the Inn in Whiterun. I do not know how this is, but what I do know is that Ysolda said she would become new owner of the inn once she earns money form trading with Khajiits. I gave her a mammoth tusk, so I don't know it that's going to make her merchant, but it there any way to make Ysolda new Innkeeper of the Bannered Mare?

Comment: If the original owner Died by some mysterious accident, like a Dragonborn use wrong Shout in front of her

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ysolda is scripted to take over the Bannered Mare upon the death of Hulda.

To make Ysolda the innkeeper of the Bannered Mare, you'll have to [kill Hulda](https://youtu.be/OsslFdexNWA?t=14m58s), or get her to die in some manner.

However, Ysolda is [also scripted to take over some other shops upon the death of their owner](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ysolda#Trivia). She will not appear in all the shops at the same time. I am not sure exactly what would happen.

Comment: I can say this:  In my one play-through where I married Ysolda and had her live at Lakeview, Belethor died (darn vampires) and no one ran his shop for the rest of the game.  The door stayed locked, and if I broke in during normal hours, I was asked to leave by his assistant.